# Quickblox: not getting contact list from EJabber

Tags: android, chat, quickblox

I'm retrvieing the user's list from quickblox by using getUsersByPhoneNumbers method. In response I got the details of users whose phone number I passed in this method but after that my app shows that blank request is sent and received in presence and messages for chat. I'm sharing my code details here :

```
private void loadNextPage() {
//  ++currentPage;

    QBPagedRequestBuilder pagedRequestBuilder = new QBPagedRequestBuilder();
    pagedRequestBuilder.setPage(1);
    pagedRequestBuilder.setPerPage(50);

    //ArrayList<String> phone_string = new ArrayList<String>();
    System.out.println("newUsers..ByPhone no>>"+newUsers);
    ArrayList<String> phones  = new ArrayList<String>();
    phones.add("8765678456");
    phones.add("98067583875");
    phones.add("9854897659");
    phones.add("9352085748");


    System.out.println("usersIds..ByPhone no>>"+phones );

    QBUsers.getUsersByPhoneNumbers(phones, pagedRequestBuilder, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<ArrayList<QBUser>>()  {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ArrayList<QBUser> users, Bundle params) {
            System.out.println("onSuccessUsers"+users);
            users.addAll(newUsers);
    }

        @Override
        public void onError(List<String> errors){

        }

});
```

and my log details are:

```
06-15 18:31:57.961: I/System.out(23029): onSuccessUsers[QBUser{id=3499103, createdAt=Fri Jun 12 12:50:46 GMT+05:30 2015, updatedAt=Fri Jun 12 12:50:46 GMT+05:30 2015, fullName='null', email='null', login='MAdapp38990523', phone='9000000000', website='null', lastRequestAt='Fri Jun 12 13:01:34 GMT+05:30 2015', externalId=null, facebookId=null, twitterId=null, blobId=null, tags='null', password='null', oldPassword='null', customData='null'}
06-15 18:31:57.961: I/System.out(23029): , QBUser{id=3566557, createdAt=Mon Jun 15 11:47:35 GMT+05:30 2015, updatedAt=Mon Jun 15 11:47:35 GMT+05:30 2015, fullName='Abhilasha', email='abhi@gmail.com', login='null', phone='8239309713', website='null', lastRequestAt='null', externalId=null, facebookId=null, twitterId=null, blobId=null, tags='null', password='null', oldPassword='null', customData='null'}
06-15 18:31:57.961: I/System.out(23029): , QBUser{id=3566609, createdAt=Mon Jun 15 11:50:18 GMT+05:30 2015, updatedAt=Mon Jun 15 11:50:18 GMT+05:30 2015, fullName='null', email='null', login='MAdapp95850548', phone='9582365285', website='null', lastRequestAt='null', externalId=null, facebookId=null, twitterId=null, blobId=null, tags='null', password='null', oldPassword='null', customData='null'}
06-15 18:31:57.961: I/System.out(23029): , QBUser{id=3570949, createdAt=Mon Jun 15 16:34:23 GMT+05:30 2015, updatedAt=Mon Jun 15 16:34:23 GMT+05:30 2015, fullName='null', email='null', login='MAdapp76801609', phone='9829079973', website='null', lastRequestAt='null', externalId=null, facebookId=null, twitterId=null, blobId=null, tags='null', password='null', oldPassword='null', customData='null'}
06-15 18:31:57.961: I/System.out(23029): ]
06-15 18:32:16.946: D/SMACK(23029): SENT (0): <presence id='6gARC-28'></presence>
06-15 18:32:17.186: D/SMACK(23029): RCV (0): <presence id="6gARC-28" to="3157814-23812@chat.quickblox.com" from="3157814-23812@chat.quickblox.com/ccd8e69b3cfdf742" xmlns="jabber:client"/>
```

Please anyone help me and explain where I'm going wrong.

Comment: What do you expect here? What are your needs?

Comment: @IgorKhomenko Quickblox sample chat code is giving me all users from server which are shown in My App contact list. When I click on any  user, then I can establish a chat window with them and messages are also getting send and receive.                                                               But I just want to pass my device/phone contact list all numbers to quickblox, verify which of those numbers are registered on quickblox , get in return those users details like their name, username, password, blob id, etc and want only those contacts to be shown on my contact screen

Comment: @IgorKhomenko currently when I pass my phone numbers list then in return I get user's details, but my Contact Screen just keeps on loading and I'm getting this log:                                                                                                06-15 18:32:16.946: D/SMACK(23029): SENT (0): <presence id='6gARC-28'></presence>
06-15 18:32:17.186: D/SMACK(23029): RCV (0): <presence id="6gARC-28" to="3157814-23812@chat.quickblox.com" from="3157814-23812@chat.quickblox.com/ccd8e69b3cfdf742" xmlns="jabber:client"/>

Comment: This is just a presence to server in your log, nothing useful...
Can you share your contact list data provider?